# UITextField on new screen will not accept input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm modifying an existing iPad app in Xcode. The app is very simple, consisting for 4 screens that collect information and send it to a web service.

I'm trying to add an additional screen with four text fields. NONE of the text fields will accept any input. I have gone through the view heierarchy and confirmed that all views have User Interaction Enabled, and none are configured for multitouch.

I have added the UITextFieldDelegate to the view controller and have connected the UITextField delegate to the view controller.

I added an NSLog to textFieldShouldBeginEditing and it does display in the console every time I touch the field. But it does not show a cursor and it does not show the keyboard.

And just because I thought I may be losing my mind, I replaced the whole screen with a blank view controller with just a single text field and it STILL will not accept any input.

Further, just to make sure I wasn't losing grip on reality, I created a new project consisting of one view with one text field and it DOES work as expected.

I really don't know where to go from here. All of the text fields on the other screens in my app are working fine. It's just for the life of me I can't get the text fields on a new screen to work.

HELP!!

Mark

```
//
//  TestViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

And

```
//
//  TestViewController.m
//

#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldBeginEditing");
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldEndEditing");
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldEndEditing");
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you test direct on device and others versions of simulator?

Comment: Inside `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, try adding this line: `[textField becomeFirstResponder];`

Comment: I added [textField becomeFirstResponder]; in textFieldShouldBeginEditing. Now I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in [UIViewController loadViewIfRequired];

Comment: Yes, @alexandresoli, I did test on my iPad. Same problem.

Comment: It is a very odd problem. My thought is that you are not presenting your new view properly thereby not allowing the user to properly interact with the textfields. This would also explain why you can get it to work with a new app but not when modifying the old one. I don't think it is an issue with your textfield but rather the users ability to interact with the textfield.

Comment: Yes, @MikeZ. Even if I try adding a bone-stock UIViewController with one UITextField it exhibits the same problem. I'm just not sure where to begin looking for the problem.

Comment: Can you post your code that shows how you are presenting the view controllers?

Comment: @MikeZ: I edited my OP to include the code.

Comment: if you're getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS while sending a message to textField (as Malloc suggested) then it has been released hence it won't show keyboard. The delegate, though, has not been released so you can receiving messages to delegate and see NSLog's output (correct me if I'm explaining it in wrong way). That means you are adding your view incorrectly. You should provide the code not only from TestViewController, but from its parent, so we can see how do you do the TestController's presenting (-presentViewController or so)

Comment: There is no code. The screen is launched from a segue in StoryBoard.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a new project from scratch, laying out all my screens and UITextFields first, wiring everything to the code and testing it first. Then I went back and added the rest of the graphic elements.

I have no idea what caused the original issue. I'll write it off as an Xcode bug.

Comment: Upvoting, because I had the same issue in a share extension and got resolved by doing `Product > Clean` and `Product > Clean Build Folder ...` and restarting Xcode. This may even be "just" a simulator issue, because after later I had this one in the containing app as well, and simply restarting the Simulator did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You try by adding **`textfield.delegate = self`** manually to `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method in that controller .. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I assigned the delegate in Interface Builder. I know the delegate is working correctly because the NSLog message I put in textFieldShouldBeginEditing is displaying to the console every time I click the UITextField.